# sklearn's feature importances_

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am just curious on the interpretation of sklearn's feature_importances_ attribute. I know that the features with highests coefficients are the features that would highly predict the outcome. My question is - Are these the features strongly predictive to return a 1 (or yes) or not necessarily? (Supervised Learning - Binary response - yes(1) or no(0)).

For example, after building the predictive model, I found out that these words are the top features - insider-trading, theft, embezzlement, investment. The response is 'illegal'(1) or 'legal'(0).

Does it mean that when a certain text has those words, there's a huge chance it's illegal or not necessarily? And, it just simply means that the value of these words would lead to a strong prediction (either illegal or legal). Appreciate any answer to such.

Answer (score 0):

It means those words are "strongly associated" with one of the responses, in your case probably `illegal(1)`. Depending on your classifier, the exact technical definition of strongly associated will vary. It could be the joint probability of the word and response, `P(X='theft', Y='illegal'), or it could be the conditional probability`P(X='theft' | Y='illegal').

Intuitively, whenever these terms appear in a document, the probability of that document belonging to the `illegal` category is increased.

Comment: Probability doesn't come into it, while that last sentence is confusing, saying that the high feature importance means it's more likely illegal. No; high feature importance means the feature is very informative towards a decision, for/against any class (as suggested by your first sentence)